# (Blogger) Map GoDaddy Domain For Blogger Custom Domain

Tags: dns, godaddy, blogger

I just bought a new domain from GoDaddy (nurayka.net) and I want to use it for my .blogspot.com blog now. Here is my Blogger [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wPMc.png). And here is my GoDaddy DNS [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbAH8.png). After more than 24 hours, I still can't view my blog with that custom domain. It seems that it might be something wrong with my DNS settings.

1. Does my DNS settings correct?
2. Does GoDaddy Domain Forwarding should be enabled from 'nurayka.net' to 'www.nurayka.net'?

Note:
Before this, I have go through the [GoDaddy Blogger DNS Setup](http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=1233381&page=ts.cs) and [CNAME Tutorial](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5112/mapping-your-domain-name-to-work-with-blogger). In the GoDaddy Blogger DNS Setup, I entered 'www.nurayka.net' and in the CNAME record (www), I entered 'ghs.google.com'.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, the problem is due to issues at the Blogger / Google end.

This is their latest Known Issues announcement:   http://knownissues.blogspot.com/2012/09/update-on-custom-domains.html

From info on the Blogger Product Forum, it looks like an issue with Google's DNS services (ie not just Blogger).

Comment: Yes. I just knew about this from GoDaddy support team. The issue still unsolved. Btw, thank you for sharing your idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your naked domain forwarded to your www subdomain? your website may be only visible on www if you havn't forwarded your naked domain.
2. Have you saved your Google settings?! sorry, I just asked this based on your images :)

A DNS change may take about 48 hours to take effect, just wait and it should be fine if you have done it according to the tutorials.

Also I must say there is nothing easier in web business than setting up GoDaddy with Blogger. if you have problems just send an email to GoDaddy and they'll probably reply in about an hour.

Comment: Already contacted GoDaddy support about this issue. Thank you. :)